# PDFBox unicode font issue - Bangla unicode font is broken in generated PDF using PDFbox in Java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, bangla-font

I want to generate a **PDF** that contains **Bangla text**. After generating PDF, text in generated PDF is **broken**. I have gone through a lot of Q/A related to this problem in StackOverflow, but unfortunately, I didn't find any suitable answer. here is my code...

```
try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()) {
    PDPage pdPage = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
    doc.addPage(pdPage);

    PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, pdPage);

    InputStream fontFileStream = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/SolaimanLipi_22-02-2012.ttf");

    PDFont banglaFont = PDType0Font.load(doc, fontFileStream, false);

    cs.beginText();
    cs.setFont(banglaFont, FONT_SIZE);
    cs.newLineAtOffset(30, 500);
    cs.showText("অভিনন্দন! প্রিয়  আবিদ হাসান,");
    cs.endText();
    cs.close();
    doc.save(location);

} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("PDF Error : {}", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

My expected output in generated PDF.

[image]

But What I got in generated PDF (Broken).

[image]

Can anyone please help me to sort out this problem???

Comment: Complex scripts are not supported. There was an effort to do this but it stopped. If you're using the trunk and build it, you could try. It works with bengali if the fonts are not subsetted, I don't know if it would work with bangla. I tried it and it seems ok, but I'm obviously unqualified to recognize the glyphs.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4189

Comment: Bengali is now part of 3.0.0. In 3.0.2 Devanagari and Gujarati will be supported. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5729